# AWS Route53 sub domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-route53

Can anyone tell me how to set a sub-domain in AWS Route53?

I am entirely new to AWS and a few hours ago I needed to setup a domain name to point at an EC2 instance.

I successfully created a hosting zone with my registered domain configured.

Next, I created an A record and specified the IP Address of the EC2 instance.

My problem is my website, on the EC2 instance, is in a subdirectory. So when I attempt to save the value of the A record as `*.*.*.*/my-subsite`, the Route53 system refuses to accept my input.

I received the following error:

> The record set could not be saved because:
>   - The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @Chris, for your answer. I did as you directed and configured `documentroot` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to `my-site`.

My problem is there is a subsite beneath my-site. I created `/etc/apache2/sites-available/sub-site.conf` and set `documentroot` to `my-subsite/sub-site`.

However, when I attempt visiting www.mysite.com/subsite, the browser redirects to www.mysite.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS is a mapping from a hostname to an IP address, period.

You will need to configure your web server so that it delivers your content from the appropriate directory.  If you're using an apache web server, you want to set the [DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) to the appropriate directory.